# Yii framework deployment

Tags: php, deployment, yii

I'm deploying a new yii app on a production server, the server has been recently configured to host the app and all yii requirements hav been installed successfully (ran yii/requirements). The problem is that none of the controller/action, in the entire site are working but site/default/index. I'm accessing through the server IP, so when I write like this 62.75.203.71, the main page (site(default/index) is showed, but when I click on any link, or write another route, then not found error is generated, e.g. 62.75.203.71/site/show

The site is working properly in my development pc, don't know if this is a yii config I'm missing or a server problem.

and also this is my config file:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

and here is the content of my .htaccess file

AllowOverride all

and I got the 404-not found ngnix 1.14!

Comment: So you leave this question here for an open guessing? Please take note, that this site is not a forum and your question should contain what you have checked and tested so far. Why do you expect your site to be working? I ask that because you write it's on a different server. I would expect a different server to behave differently so I don't wonder at all that it doesn't work.

Comment: FYI, if I knew what is happening I wouldn't ask the question. And I was wonder if it is related to the .htaccess file or not??

Comment: If you are using the URL manager and friendly routes, then yes, it could be related to .htaccess. But your question is lacking in details. What does "none ... are working" mean - does it give you a 404 not found, does it show you the starting page, etc.?

Comment: I have changed the text could you please read it now thanks guys:)

Comment: @Ehsan: It's totally normal that when you do something you don't know nothing about you have hundreds of questions. But that's also the time to formulate the questions in a way that you can learn on your own. Take your questions and think about how you can solve them, e.g. by reading the manual, setup instructions etc. And while you do that, write down what you do, create an article out of it, publish it so next time you can follow your trail.

Comment: 404-not found ngnix 1.14! <-- is that Nginx? Nginx does not support .htaccess.

Comment: Yes it is 404-not found ngnix 1.14! what should I do? what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error may be your `controller` names and the names you are calling them in URLS. They are case sensitive.

Second issue i faced some times that you have modified Seo friendly urls then you may have to look over regex there

But

I am sure your `controllers` name `case` is causing this wired problem

for example
`class BookingUsersController extends Controller`
this is your controler you should use same case for characters and in your url for example

```
yii::app()->createUrl('BookingUsers')
```

using this would not work

```
yii::app()->createUrl('bookingusers')
```

or vice versa change the case of that controler ,view everywhere

Answer (score 0):

I would look for any http config differences between your dev and production servers.  Chances are that there is a difference between the URL rewrite rules that are being applied in the two environments.  This would cause the URLs that you're code is generating to not resolve properly.

Comment: I think the problem is it's not recognizing my yii framework but it's recognizing it in my local machine

Comment: In that case, check your index.php file and make sure the $yii variable at the top of the file has the correct path to your Yii framework directory.